# how to launch local application through Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of achieving the end result but what I have works so far.  I have a Google sheet with multiple tabs of data.  What I would like to do is launch a local Windows application (e.g. mstsc.exe / notepad.exe) when I select a cell on a particular sheet.  I am not even sure if this is possible as I have found no clear answer from searching.

I already make use of the onEdit function to get the active sheet name and cell and then call a sub-function which colors the cell depending on the value set and updates the time stored in a different cell.  Reduced extract of code below: -

```
function onEdit(){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();  
 if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Test Sheet"){
   if( cell.getColumn() == 3 ) { //checks the column
   // change colors to meet your needs
   ColourCell()
   }
}


function ColourCell(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  // change colors to meet your needs
   var status = cell.getValue();
   var color;
   switch(status ) {
     case "COMPLETE":
       color = "LIME";
       sheet.getActiveCell().setBackgroundColor(color);
       var nextCell = cell.offset(0, 3);
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+1", "HH:mm:ss");
       nextCell.setValue(time)
     break;
     case "OPEN":
       color = "RED";
       sheet.getActiveCell().setBackgroundColor(color);       
       var nextCell = cell.offset(0, 1); 
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+1", "HH:mm:ss");
       nextCell.setValue(time)
     break;
 }
};
```

What I have tried to do is add a further if statement to the onEdit function which would then call a LaunchApp function as shown below

```
if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Test Sheet"){
 if( cell.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column
  // change colors to meet your needs
  ColourCell()
 }
 if( cell.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
  // launch mstsc and connect to value in cell
  LaunchApp() 
 }  
}


function LaunchApp(){
// WHAT CODE NEEDS TO BE ADDED HERE ????
};
```

But I cannot work out what code would need to go in the LaunchApp function or, as I mentioned earlier, even if this is possible.

Can anyone offer me some help ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script is purely web-based language. Moreover it is executed at server's side. Thus it is impossible to launch an application locally.

However, you could mark selected cell in some way (color, font, etc.) and then try to check the mark with locally installed app. The app would have to use Google Drive API but you can write it using any common programming language: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/downloads